# Core Data: computed property in extension is "called" when object is saved

Tags: swift, core-data

My NSManagedObject has an extension with a computed property:

```
extension MyNSManagedObjectSubclass {
    var myComputedProperty: String {
        return "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
```

When I'm editing the object and save it back to core data, after the `save()` that code is executed - why is this?

Answer (score 0):

- Click once inside the scope of the method or select it.
- Click on the symbol [image] on top left of the Editor window.
- Select `Callers`. It shows you all locations where the method is called.

Comment: doesn't help at all; `Callers` is empty (maybe because it's Swift in a mixed project) - but when I search for occurrences of the property (not method!) I find two places - but none of them is called at that point.